# Two sample T test in R

Tags: r

How do I run a T test comparing groups I and B  by there accuracy? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a84Ib.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Quick tip: it is always a good idea to give us your data not as image, but in text. This is preferably done with `dput()`.

Comment: Also please include code you have tried to show you've made an attempt and any errors you are getting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R - fast two sample t test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58419215/r-fast-two-sample-t-test)

Answer (score 0):

The command you are looking for is `t.test()`. In your case, it should look like:

```
t.test(accuracy ~ group, data = DATA_NAME)
```